# How to accomplish this complex mapping with template metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, struct, metaprogramming

I'm trying to define a struct using template metaprogramming but what I'm trying to do may need to be spread over multiple structs instead of having one super struct:

```
template <A, B, C>
struct ABC
{
   A a;
   B b;
   C c;
}
```

Here's the flexible I hope to achieve as I will be using a code-generator and would prefer not to have to define each possible struct-type concretely if at all possible:

1. Types for A, B and C can be defined.
2. a, b or c can be pre-defined and pre-assigned constants (i.e, const unsigned char a = 0x48; ) or be regular variable member types.

The general pattern is I will have unsigned numeric input for b in my code-generator, c will generally be integral (of 1-8 bytes in length) and a will be the resulting total length of the struct.

Some examples (not exactly what is needed but to give an idea):

```
struct <struct1>
{
   const unsigned char a = 'A';
   const unsigned short b = 0x1000;
   char c[10];
}
```

I don't know enough about template meta-programming to even begin going about doing this particularly for the a and b parts where they can be pre-assigned or not.

Perhaps to keep it easy, we can get away with assuming that I will always assign values to A, B, C and a, and b so a and b can be constants and pre-assigned.

In the end these messages will be casted to char* and sent over the wire (and byte-packed using #pragma)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Sorry for the confusing problem description.  I will try to clarify it with some examples of what I would like to accomplish using the templated struct ABC (or with additional structs defined as needed).  These examples are from the end-user perspective:

```
typedef ABC<100, char[10]> Msg1;
```

would result in the equivalent of:

```
struct Msg1
{
    const unsigned short a = sizeof(Msg1); // sizeof(Msg1) fits in unsigned short
    const unsigned char b = 100;
    char[512] c;
}
```

Note the size of members a and b need to be determined by the template based on the size of Msg1 and the passed in parameter 100.  This is the tricky part for me.

```
typedef ABC<23000, unsigned int> Msg2;

struct Msg2
{
    const unsigned char a = sizeof(Msg2);  // sizeof(Msg2) fits in unsigned char
    const unsigned short b = 23000;
    unsigned int c;
}
```

Hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Have you looked at tuples? (`std(::tr1)::tuple` or `boost::tuple`)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get at all what the problem is. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Well, to define the struct with constants, you can just use plain templates:

```
template <typename A, A a_val,
          typename B, B a_val,
          typename C, C a_val>
struct ABC
{
  static const A a = a_val;
  static const B b = b_val;
  static const C c = c_val;
}
```

This works as long as the types are integral. Usage:

```
ABC<char, 'a', unsigned int, 12, std::size_t, 100> abc;
```

If you need an arbitrary number of such pairs, this could be generalized with variadic templates. I made the constants static since they're a property of the type, not the instance. Using a constructor, this can easily be extended to non-integral types.

This is probably not quite what you want, so please do leave a comment if I misunderstood, or update your question to clarify the specifications.

Comment: This is a good approach although it seems to be a bit more brute-force...  Also, members A, B and C aren't necessarily const static all the time.  Is there a way to use templates to specify this?

Comment: @user: Sure, you can use a constructor initializer list. But if the values are part of the *type*, then surely they're static? Anyway, let me know if you want anything specific.

Answer (score 1):

It's not abundantly clear what you are wanting to do, but from what I can gather, here goes. Look into `boost::fusion` - could save you some effort. For example:

```
typedef unsigned char IDType
typedef unsigned short LengthType
typedef boost::array<char, 8> DataType

typedef boost::fusion::vector<IDType, LengthType, DataType> StructA;

StructA a_inst('A',0x1000, "ABCD");
```

This creates an instance of `StructA` with the given values, now if you can guarantee that the first two attributes are always constant - you can do something like this:

```
typedef <unsigned char id, unsigned short len, typename DataType>
struct generic_struct
{
  DataType _data;
};

// Now a specific type looks like this
typedef generic_struct<'A', 0x1000, boost::array<char, 8> > StructA;
```

The difference with the latter approach is that `StructA` does not require storage space for the first two consts, they are part of the *type* - this means for serialization, you need to provide a specific method which can serialize the id type and the length (template parameters) - but this is trivial.

Comment: We use `boost.fusion` and are very happy with it. +1 for great suggestion for the problem.

Comment: I really like the direction you took however I'm not able to use Boost for this particular project....

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is a way to specify a template class that wraps 2 members and adds an additional member that contains the sizeof for that template.

```
template <int B, class C>
struct tABC
{
    const size_t a;
    const unsigned int b;
    C c;

    tABC() : a(sizeof(*this)), b(B) {}
};
```

That generates basically the code you seem to be looking for. The only thing missing is that you seem to have some rules in place for how you select the type of a and b. If those are "whatever the smallest type that could hold them is", you really need to consider using boost as it has libraries designed to do just that. Otherwise, I guess just open up the boost code and copy how it does it.

Comment: is it not possible for 'a' to be assigned at compile-time rather than runtime in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to make it static. That would defeat the purpose of having 'a' as a member though.